# Force COM Port number for similar devices

Tags: windows, serial-port

I have 10 similar devices with ftdi chips on them (for USB to Serial comms) - they are exactly the same. I have a C# application running on a laptop. I understand that Windows initially needs to install the device drivers on the system before these devices can be used. My question is if it is possible to force Windows to skip the re-installation of the drivers every time any of these devices is plugged in (reducing detection time) and force Windows to use the same COM port number for all of them - regardless of which one is plugged in. I see that these devices, under Windows registry ("HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM"), have the same value name substring of 'VCP'.

Answer (score 1):

I know this problem. You simply have to use the same USB connection path (possibly even usb hubs included). Every connection path has its own COM port assignment. This is the same for Prolific chip connectors.

simply put: Just do not change any USB connections for the converters and you should be fine...

You might also want to have a look at the following FTDI-approved utilities:

'IgnoreSerialNo.exe' ('Ignore Hardware Serial Number Registry Editor Utility')
'ReAssignCOMPortNumb.exe' ('COMPort_Assignment Utility')

from http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Utilities.htm
.